# Where to find apps for Nokia Lumia 800?

Tags: store, 7.8, nokia-lumia-800

I just bought a Nokia Lumia 800 and it has Windows Phone 7.8 installed on it. All good and nice but I'm not able to download any apps. When I go to http://www.windowsphone.com, select an app (even Facebook Messenger) and tap to get app details, a black window appears (as usual), but instead of the install button there's the following message:

> This app is not compatible with your phone. This might be due to region, software need to be updated or app was created for a specific carrier.

My phone has the latest version of Windows Phone compatible with it, and the region is set to US (I've also tried many others).

Where can I download apps for this phone?

Comment: Can you download the following app? It is designed for windows phone 7 (disclaimer: it is mine), you do not have to buy it, just download the trial. If you cannot download it there is likely something wrong with your phone. http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=bcb12310-4cf3-4f26-9b19-acc1e3c66fbf

Comment: Yes I can! My question is....how can I obtain lets say...Facebook Messenger for WP7?? In the market it is for WP8 only.

Comment: Can you chat with your Facebook friends using Skype or IM+?

Comment: No, you can't :(

Comment: You can....but is not the same feeling...

Comment: @caschw - that might be an answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official dedicated Facebook Messenger app for Windows Phone 7.x; They chose to only support 8.0 (and later). There is an official [Facebook app](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e) though, which does work on Windows Phone 7.5 and later.

If I remember correctly, you can also still use Facebook chat via the built in Facebook integration via your "Me" tile (also in the address book), and set your chat status there.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to download apps for 7.8 is to use the Marketplace app that's already on the phone.  All of the apps in there will work on your phone. Most new apps that are being made for windows phones will only work on the Windows 8 phones.  As for Facebook though you don't need the app for that because it's built into the phone, you can just go the settings and add the account and then you can use the messaging part of your phone to send/receive facebook messages as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're phone is windows 7.8 and cannot be upgraded to windows 8, so that you cant install any apps that works with windows 8 or Later.